# onServiceConnected not called

Tags: android, google-play-services, cordova-plugins, apk-expansion-files

I'm developing a cordava plugin that manages my expansion files for android. The reading of an expansion file works, but I have problems with downloading them.

Here is my plugin:

```
public class ExpansionFileReader extends CordovaPlugin implements IDownloaderClient {

    private final String MEDIA_FOLDER_NAME = "mediafiles";
    private final String MAIN_EXPANSION = "main_expansion";
    private final String URL = "url";
    private final String TAG = "expansionFileReader";

    private Context context;
    private CallbackContext callbackContext;   


    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    }

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject callbackValue = new JSONObject();
        context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("downloadExpansionFileIfNecessary")) {
            this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
            downloadExpansionFileIfNecessary();

        } else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("getFile")){

            [getFileAction]

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void downloadExpansionFileIfNecessary() {

        if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NO EXPANSION FILE FOUND");
            try {
                Intent launchIntent = this.cordova.getActivity().getIntent();
                Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent((context), context.getClass());
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

                if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
                    for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
                        intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
                    }
                }

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((context), 0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                // Request to start the download
                Log.d(TAG, "REQUEST TO START DOWNLOAD");
                int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context, pendingIntent, DownloaderService.class);

                if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {

                    mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this, DownloaderService.class);
                    if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
                        mDownloaderClientStub.connect(context);
                    }

                    return;
                } 
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DOWNLOAD NOT NECESSARY");
                    callbackContext.success();
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot find package!", e);
            }
        } else {
            validateXAPKZipFiles();
        }
    }


    /////////////////////////////
    // INIT DOWNLOADS
    /////////////////////////////

    private IDownloaderService mRemoteService;
    private IStub mDownloaderClientStub;
    private int mState;
    private boolean mCancelValidation;

    // region Expansion Downloader
    private static class XAPKFile {
        public final boolean mIsMain;
        public final int mFileVersion;
        public final long mFileSize;

        XAPKFile(boolean isMain, int fileVersion, long fileSize) {
            mIsMain = isMain;
            mFileVersion = fileVersion;
            mFileSize = fileSize;
        }
    }

    private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
            new XAPKFile(
                    true, // true signifies a main file
                    1000006, // the version of the APK that the file was uploaded against
                    443975466L // the length of the file in bytes
            )
    };
    static private final float SMOOTHING_FACTOR = 0.005f;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON START");
        if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
            mDownloaderClientStub.connect(context);
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON STOP");
        if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
            mDownloaderClientStub.disconnect(context);
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(Messenger m) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON SERVICE CONNECTED");
        mRemoteService = DownloaderServiceMarshaller.CreateProxy(m);
        mRemoteService.onClientUpdated(mDownloaderClientStub.getMessenger());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStateChanged(int newState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON DOWNLOAD STATE CHANGED: " + newState);
        setState(newState);
        boolean showDashboard = true;
        boolean showCellMessage = false;
        boolean paused;
        boolean indeterminate;
        switch (newState) {
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_IDLE:
                // STATE_IDLE means the service is listening, so it's
                // safe to start making calls via mRemoteService.
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = true;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_CONNECTING:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FETCHING_URL:
                showDashboard = true;
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = true;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_DOWNLOADING:
                paused = false;
                showDashboard = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;

            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_CANCELED:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_UNLICENSED:
                paused = true;
                showDashboard = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_NEED_CELLULAR_PERMISSION:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_WIFI_DISABLED_NEED_CELLULAR_PERMISSION:
                showDashboard = false;
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                showCellMessage = true;
                break;

            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_BY_REQUEST:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_ROAMING:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_SDCARD_UNAVAILABLE:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_COMPLETED:
                showDashboard = false;
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                validateXAPKZipFiles();
                return;
            default:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = true;
                showDashboard = true;
        }            
    }


    @Override
    public void onDownloadProgress(DownloadProgressInfo progress) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ON DOWNLOAD PROGESS: " + progress);            
    }


    boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
        Log.d(TAG, "IF EXPANSION FILE IS DELIVERED");
        for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
            String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(context, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
            if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(context, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "EXPANSION FILE DOESN'T EXIST");
                return false;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "EXPANSION FILE EXIST");
        return true;
    }

}
```

My problem is that `onServiceConnected` is never called although I call `mDownloaderClientStub.connect(context);`

Does anybody know why it is not called? I'm getting no error either.

Answer (score 0):

The service connection could not be established because you pass an incorrect `Class` object into the expansion library methods.

You should change the argument in the call to `DownloaderClientMarshaller` from `DownloaderService.class` to `MyDownloaderService.class` or whichever class you use to extend the base `DownloaderService`. Also, make sure that your service is defined in your app's manifest.

```
// use the correct service class!
int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context, pendingIntent, MyDownloaderService.class);

// when creating a stub also
mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub(this, MyDownloaderService.class);
```

I recommend using the updated Downloader Library included in [Better APK Expansion](https://github.com/bolein/better-apk-expansion) package. It has this and other issues fixed and also provides simplified API that minimizes chances to shoot yourself in the foot.